# SSH не сохраняет пароли

Tags: macos, ssh, svn, openssh

Использую Mac OS 10.15.4
Почему-то не сохраняются ключи при ssh подключениях.

Например, используя команду `svn update` у меня каждый раз запрашивает пароль, при этом `~/.ssh/config` такой:

```
Host *
    user evgeniy
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    UseKeychain yes
```

Подскажите плз, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А svn у вас ходит по ssh?

Comment: да, svn+ssh://путь